# convert uint to const name

Tags: c#, constants

I have some constant error codes in a class:

```
 public class EDSDK
 {
    public const uint EDS_ERR_UNIMPLEMENTED = 0x00000001;  
    public const uint EDS_ERR_INTERNAL_ERROR = 0x00000002;
    public const uint EDS_ERR_MEM_ALLOC_FAILED = 0x00000003;

}
```

How can I get the const name from an (hex encoded) value?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1064213/determine-the-name-of-a-constant-based-on-the-value might be helpful

Comment: If you want a mapping between integers and names that's accessible at runtime, perhaps you're looking for an `enum` rather than separate `const`s

Comment: (can't add a comment, so im posting it here):
see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1064213/determine-the-name-of-a-constant-based-on-the-value

Comment: The name is a variable name, it has no place in compiled code. What are you trying to do?

Comment: @Sayse: Well it *is* in the compiled code...

Comment: What would you expect to happen if you had multiple constants with the same value? What are you trying to achieve?

Comment: @Sayse: Not really, to be honest.

Comment: @JonSkeet - I mean it isn't really useful to rely on the name of a variable to then be used in any form of program's flow, as Damien mentioned an enum sounds close to what the OP might be after, but without any explanation it would only be guess work

Comment: @Sayse: I agree that an enum would be better, but I think it's also reasonable to rely on publicly-exposed names via reflection. (If it were private, or a local variable, that would be a different matter.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you use `enum`, it can be done with `Enum.ToString()`:

```
public enum EDSDK
{
    EDS_ERR_UNIMPLEMENTED = 0x00000001,
    EDS_ERR_INTERNAL_ERROR = 0x00000002,
    EDS_ERR_MEM_ALLOC_FAILED = 0x00000003
}



EDSDK status = (EDSDK)0x00000001;
string statusString = status.ToString();
```